# When the page is scrolling the selected dropdown value will change in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown, dynamic-ui

I'll change a dropdown balue `1lakh` to `Rs. 6000` then I scroll the screen. The selected dropdown value will be changed.

[image]

refer to my Dropdown custom widget
I'll pass on all details to the widget. title, DropdownMenuItems, the callback function, and also give a initially selected value.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:insurance/widgets/common/colors.dart';

class DropdownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.dropdownList,
      required this.selectedValue,
      required this.callback});
  final String title;
  final List<String> dropdownList;
  final String selectedValue;
  final Function callback;

  @override
  State<DropdownWidget> createState() => _DropdownWidgetState();
}

class _DropdownWidgetState extends State<DropdownWidget> {
  late String title = widget.title, selectedValue = widget.selectedValue;
  late List<String> dropdownList = widget.dropdownList;
  late Function callback = widget.callback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListTile(
        title: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
              Visibility(
                  child: title == 'Seating Capacity'
                      ? Text(
                          ' *',
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColor.red),
                        )
                      : const Text(''))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.40,
          height: 50,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColor.white,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7))),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: selectedValue,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
              items: dropdownList.map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: value,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
                    child: Text(
                      value.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          color: AppColor.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? selectedData) {
                print('hello');
                callback(selectedData);

                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = selectedData!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and also the same issue on the flutter switch button
What should I do?

Comment: can you tell us what's the problem exactly

Comment: the exact issue is. using the custom dropdown widget initially works well when I change the value and then scroll the screen. the selected value will be changed

Comment: try with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin mixin`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your custom Dropdown widget directly inside the ListView widget replace with SingleChildScrollview (child: Column( children: [  DropdownWidget]),